# Nodejs readdir - only find files

Tags: node.js, readdir

When reading a directory, I currently have this:

```
  fs.readdir(tests, (err, items) => {

      if(err){
        return cb(err);
      }

      const cmd = items.filter(v => fs.lstatSync(tests + '/' + v).isFile());

      k.stdin.end(`${cmd}`);
  });
```

first of all I need a try/catch in there around fs.lstatSync, which I don't want to add. **But is there a way to use `fs.readdir` to only find files?**

Something like:

```
fs.readdir(tests, {type:'f'}, (err, items) => {});
```

does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `fs.readdir` doesn't have an option to specify that you're only looking for files, not folders/directories (per docs). Filtering the results from `fs.readdir` to knock out the directories is your best bet.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

> The optional `options` argument can be a string specifying an
>   encoding, or an object with an `encoding` property specifying the
>   character encoding to use for the filenames passed to the callback. If
>   the `encoding` is set to `'buffer'`, the filenames returned will be
>   passed as `Buffer` objects.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from node v10.10.0, you can add `withFileTypes` as options parameter to get `fs.Dirent` instead of string.

```
// or readdir to get a promise
const subPaths = fs.readdirSync(YOUR_BASE_PATH, { 
  withFileTypes: true
});
// subPaths is fs.Dirent[] type
const directories = subPaths.filter((dirent) => dirent.isFile());
// directories is string[] type
```

more info is located at node documentation:

- [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent)
- [fs.readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)
- [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah `fs.readdir` can't do this currently (only read files or only read dirs).

I filed an issue with Node.js and looks like it may be a good feature to add.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21804

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is scripting/automation. You might try [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) library. That can find files in folder for you, but also can be configured for much more sophisticated searches.

```js
const jetpack = require("fs-jetpack");

// Find all files in my_folder
const filesInFolder = jetpack.find("my_folder", { recursive: false }));
console.log(filesInFolder);

// Example of more sophisticated search:
// Find all `.js` files in the folder tree, with modify date newer than 2020-05-01
const borderDate = new Date("2020-05-01")
const found = jetpack.find("foo", {
  matching: "*.js",
  filter: (file) => {
    return file.modifyTime > borderDate
  }
});
console.log(found);
```